# Which spatial data structure is fastest for a set of non-intersecting AABBs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, spatial

Consider a warehouse of non-intersecting axis-aligned boxes. With which data structure I can find a spot for a box, get all free volume as a set of AABBs, or get a list of intersected boxes in the fastest way?

Boxes have integer positions and sizes. The warehouse size is 300x300x10. There are up to few thousand boxes.

Storage is not an issue, but it should be reasonable (say, up to O(N^2)).

It is ok if all three cases require three different answers. I know common spatial data structures, but I stuggle with what kind of optimizations can I apply in my case.

Comment: Your warehouse size is rather small (less than a million cells), so looping naively though them should not be a problem (a 3D boolean array would do the job). Are you sure that this is what you want to optimize ?
A famous saying is that *early optimization is the source of all evil*. I suggest that you first verify that this is indeed the bottleneck of your program, and only then go for some optimization.

Comment: Well, this is a hobby project, so I have a freedom to play around impractical tasks. While there are plenty of methods where I could optimize it by power of ten times, it still leaves me with 10^4-10^5 operations to generate the warehouse. Later, I would use this optimization for pathfinding with a power of thousand agents.

Comment: Having a boolean array was my first idea. Unfortunately, it is slower than to bruteforce all AABBs for intersections. Then I used a BVH, and it made generation faster by five times. I would prefer something even faster, and I found surprisingly little information for my specific case. Maybe that's because the case is specific, maybe because my set of conditions is already handled by some common approach, and I failed to recognize that.

Comment: Now I think of improving the boolean array approach. The main issue is that I have to check every cell individually. What I could do is to store a reference to the AABB in every cell, including empty AABBs. Every AABB could store 3 lists of its neughbouring AABBs, one for every axis. When I would add a new box to the warehouse, I would split empty AABB in up to seven AABBs (one is the box and the rest is free volume). Then I would start from the min corner and check the current area and its neughbours recursively until I reach the max corner.

Comment: When the condition is the spatial XYZ data, I advise to use a quad-treee, or even an octree.

Comment: do you need dynamic updates?

Comment: @MattTimmermans no. Once a box is placed, it stays.